# Casting from abstract base class pointer to derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to create a state manager for my game, and I have 4 classes:

GameState:

```
  // foward declaration to avoid circular-referency
  class StateManager;

  class GameState
  {
    public:
      virtual ~GameState() { }    
      virtual void update(StateManager* gameManager) = 0;
      virtual void draw(StateManager* gameManager) = 0;

   protected:
      GameState() { }
  };
```

StateManager:

```
  class StateManager
  {
    public:
      StateManager();
      virtual ~StateManager();

      void addState(GameState* gameState);
      void update(StateManager* stateManager);
      void draw(StateManager* stateManager);

    protected:
      // store states in a unique_ptr to avoid memory leak
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState> > states_;
  };
```

Game:

```
class Game : public StateManager
{
public:
  void compute()
  {
    // call methos of statemanager
    update(this);
    draw(this);
  }
}
```

And MainMenu:

```
class MainMenu : public GameState
{
  public:
    // override the pure virtual methos of GameState
    void update(StateManager* stateManager)
    {
      // problem here.
      // I need to handle instance of Game in this class, 
      // but the pointer is one StateManager
    }
    void draw(StateManager* stateManager) {}
}
```

When I initialize my game like so: `game.addState(new MainMenu())`.

The only way I can access the class `Game` in `MainMenu` is by casting the pointer?

```
// MainMenu class
void update(StateManager* stateManager)
{
    Game* game = (Game*) stateManager;
    game.input.getKey(ANY_KEY);
    //...
}
```

Is this right? Something tells me I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: _"Something tells me I'm doing wrong."_ What is that something?

Comment: Everyone wants all the benefits of polymorphism combined with all the benefits of concrete classes, and it's messy. You need to `dynamic_cast` your `StateManager*` into a `Game*`. It returns `nullptr` on failure.

Comment: `StateManager::update` and `StateManager::draw` take two `StateManager` objects as input - is this meaningful?  I would change `addState` to `void addState(std::unique_ptr<GameState>);` to make it clear it takes ownership.

Comment: Are not necessary, in my code they do not exist. Is not better that ```game.addState(new Level ())``` than this: ```std::unique_ptr <gamestate> state(new Level ());
game.addState (state);``` ??

Comment: Why do `StateManager` `update` and `draw` even take `StateManager*` as a parameter? And you are using normal pointers there, so it is very hard to say what is the intent behind the methods. Sharing ownership, passing, callback? Usually down-casting indicates a design problem/flaw. Are you guaranteed the object is of a `Derived` type? If so why do you pass it as `Base`. If not, why not and why do you allow yourself to "lose" (you loose static) type information when you actually need it.

Comment: i cant do that ```MainMenu::update(Game* game);``` because ```MainMenu``` inherite ```GameState``` class that have this method: ```virtual void update(StateManager* stateManager) = 0;```. If you know a better way to tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of **immibis** is perfect for addressing the technical casting issue.

Nevertheless there's something weird in your design. So I'd like to provide an alternative answer, addressing the design issues.

First a `StateManager` is not itself a `GameState`. So there is no need to have the same signature for `update()` and `draw()`.  Do you ever foresee to have one of these `StateManager` functions called with another `StateManager` in argument ?  For a `Game`, I think this makes no sense. So I'd recommend to refactor the class (and adapt `Game` accordingly):

```
class StateManager {
public:
    ...
    void update();  // they always know "this".  
    void draw();
protected:
    ...
};
```

Next, it seems that the `StateManager` owns the `GameState` (the protected vector using a `unique_ptr<>`,and your casting question suggest it).  So another design could be interesting as well:

```
class GameState {
public:
    virtual ~GameState() { }    
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;
protected:
    GameState(StateManager* gameManager) { }  // GameStates are created for a StateManager
    StateManager* gm;   // this manager can then be used for any GameState functions that need it
};
```

Following this logic, the `MainMenu` would be refactored as:

```
class MainMenu : public GameState
{
public:
    MainMenu (Game* g) : game(g), GameState(g) {}
    void update()
    {
        // NO LONGER NEEDED:  Game* game = (Game*) stateManager;
        game->input.getKey(ANY_KEY);
        // NO MORE PROBLEMS HERE:  you always refer to the right object without any overhead
    }
    void draw() {}
protected:  
    Game *game;   // the owning game.  
};
```

The advantages of this alternative design are:

- the code will be much lighter, and less error prone, as you don't always to worry about the member function's argument.
- `StateManager` pointer is used only for the `StateManager` abstraction.
- Concerete implementations of `GameState`, which rely on `Game`, can use it directly, but should use it only for Game specific abstractions.

The main inconveniences are:

- `GameState` must always be created for one specifc `StateManager`.
- The robustness of the design comes at the cost of a redundant pointer in all  `GameState` implementations such as `MainMenu` .  If you have millions of them,  it could become a memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure whether `stateManager` points to a `Game`, then use:

```
Game *game = dynamic_cast<Game*>(stateManager);
```

`game` will then contain a null pointer if `stateManager` did not point to a `Game`, otherwise it will contain a pointer to the game.

If you *are* sure it's *always* a `Game` and want to skip the check (for a tiny performance gain), use:

```
Game *game = static_cast<Game*>(stateManager);
```

which will produce undefined behaviour if `stateManager` doesn't point to a `Game`.